# vim's sftp plugin remote editing file

Tags: vim, ssh, sftp, netrw

There is a way to use Sublime Text's SFTP plugin to remote editing a file. Because my network is slow, when I want to ssh to the server to use vim to edit codes, it will be very slow. I tried vim's plugin called "netrw", but I don't like it. Could you suggest another way to use vim to edit remote server's file without delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing "user-unfriendly" in:

```
:e scp://foo@bar.baz//path/to/dir/
(edit file)
<C-^>
(edit another file)
<C-^>
(edit another file)
<C-^>
(rinse, repeat)
```

You get a file listing, you pick a file to edit, you go back to that file listing, you pick another file… simple.

Other options:

- use a dedicated SFTP client to deal with the networking part,
- use Git/Subversion/Mercurial/$VCS
- mount your SSH file system

Comment: You should take some time to RTFM before calling something user-unfriendly.